# Filtering by author in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHg 2.3.1 - I want to filter changesets by author, and I can't figure out how, couldn't find any info online either - does this option even exist?

Comment: You **really have** to read about revsets in Mercurial for using full power of CLI and Query-Builder in GUI.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Sixth button in full WorkBench Toolbar: "Fiter Graph". Just enter needed condition (see my comment) in edit-field and <strike>press small button "Trigger"</strike>enable checkbox "Filter" ("Toggle" invert filter of output, not refilter - my mistake) on the right of the edit-area (screenshot was done with TortoiseHG 2.* interface)

[image: Filtering interface]

Comment: can you give me a practical example of how to use this? I want to find all changesets for user johndoe. a link to a good tutorial on the query-builder would help. and i don't know what CLI means

Comment: CLI is Command Line Interface. My screenshot **is practical example** - I show filtered changesets list, authored only one committer with name Alexander. In order to construct own custom revsets in builder (which is only GUI) you have to understand at least [Specifying Revision Sets](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) topic

Comment: @estherh "5.4.6. Filter Toolbar" chapter in TortoiseHG Help may help for starting